# What is the operator norm of the Volterra operator on the Schwartz class

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

Let $$ A(f)(x) := \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \;dt $$

be defined on the [Schwartz space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space) $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$. Is $A$ a well-defined and bounded linear operator into $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$? If so, what is its operator norm?

Comment: It doesn't map the Schwartz class to itself, first, and, second, since the Schwartz class is not a Banach space, there's no obvious natural "operator norm".

Comment: For which $f\in \mathcal S(\Bbb R)$ will we have $A(f)\notin\mathcal S(\Bbb R)$?

Comment: Can you prove the first statement? That's true, what I meant was  the Lipschitz constant with respect to the metric, but that is irrelevant if it is not well-defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking $$f(t)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-t^2}$$ results in $A(f)(x)=\text{erf}(x)$, the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), which is obviously not a Schwartz function.